# I have installed Django currently onto 2.6.9 instead of 2.7.7 on Redhat , am I missing out on anything?

Tags: python, django, redhat

I have also implemented MongoDb, and MongoEnginge, so I don't really want to traceback and upgrade everything accordingly towards 2.7.7. Unless theres an easy way to do it. But yeah everything is currently installed under 2.6.9, and the server is on redhat 4.8.2-7 would I be missing out on anything by not upgrading to 2.7.7?